# Escaping double quotes within String.Format in C#

Tags: c#, xml, string, escaping

I am attempting to get the 'Id' property of the Parameter element to be enclosed in double quotes. I first attempted to simply escape the quotations and this is the first thing I tried to achieve this:

```
buffer = String.Format("{0}" + "<Parameter Id=" + "{1}" + ">" + "{2}" + "</Parameter>", buffer, id, param);
```

With the above code I get this back, as you can see the escape characters are showing up, along with the quotation:

```
<Conquest><User>ArchElf</User><Token>0123456789012345678901234567890</Token><Command>validate</Command><Parameter Id=\"1\">Gemstone3</Parameter>
```

My second attempt is based on advised I received on IRC, a fellow advised that I may be able to use '"' to get my quotations, ala:

```
buffer = String.Format("{0}" + "<Parameter Id=" + "&quot;" + "{1}" + "&quot;" + ">" + "{2}" + "</Parameter>", buffer, id, param);
```

This method only yielded the literal '"' string in the end result:

```
<Conquest><User>ArchElf</User><Token>0123456789012345678901234567890</Token><Command>validate</Command><Parameter Id=&quot;1&quot;>Gemstone3</Parameter>
```

In desperation I went ahead and just added the literal double quotes baked into the string.

I did this because I read at [This Codeproject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma#string.Formatescaping7) that the only characters in a String.Format that I need to worry about escaping are curly braces and(surprise, surprise) this isn't even compile-able, WITH and WITHOUT the preceding @. Shouting at me a bunch of errors including:

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
; Expected
) Expected
...and so on

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated. I know this has got to be something trivial I am missing, the best kind of conundrums. :/

Here is the entire BuildCommand method:

```
public string BuildCommand(string _command, string[] _parameters = null)
    {
        int id = 1;
        string buffer = String.Format("<Conquest><User>"+"{0}"+"</User><Token>"+"{1}"+"</Token><Command>"+"{2}"+"</Command>", _playerName, _token, _command);
        if (_parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (string param in _parameters)
            {
                if (param.Length < 1 || param == null)
                    break;
                buffer = String.Format("{0}" + "<Parameter Id=" + "{1}" + ">" + "{2}" + "</Parameter>", buffer, id, param);

                // buffer = String.Format(@"""{0}""<Parameter Id=""{1}"">""{2}""</Parameter>", buffer, id, param);
                id += 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your examples don't match up to what actually happens. Take your first example: if you actually run that code, you get this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rkXISA which isn't what you report. So something else weird is going on. Maybe your 'id' variable is a string which already has quotes in it?

Comment: Are you seeing this value from the debugger? Because, it does show escape characters which do not exist in the string. Do they still show up when you click the eyeglass icon? Or print/display them outside of the debugging tools? Is `id` a string or int? If it's a string, are you *sure* it doesn't contain the quotes itself?

Comment: Here are my values.
`<Conquest><User>ArchElf</User><Token>0123456789012345678901234567890</Token><Command>Validate</Command><Parameter Id=1>Gemstone3</Parameter></Conquest>\r\n`

Comment: @BackSlashAttack then you're doing something above and beyond the code that you've given us. You haven't told us what happens to the string between what you've shown and you printing it, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it the right way

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //<Conquest><User>ArchElf</User><Token>0123456789012345678901234567890</Token><Command>validate</Command><Parameter Id=\"1\">Gemstone3</Parameter>

            string user = "ArchElf";
            string token = "0123456789012345678901234567890";
            string command = "validate";
            int id = 1;
            string value = "Gemstrone3";
            XElement conquest = new XElement("Conquest");

            conquest.Add(new XElement("User", user));

            conquest.Add(new XElement("Token", token));

            conquest.Add(new XElement("Command", command));

            XElement e_parameter = new XElement("Parameter", value);
            e_parameter.Add(new XAttribute("Id", id));
            conquest.Add(e_parameter);
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: I understand that and there is a reason why I have not. Thank you for your input though. I'd really just like to find out the answer to the original question.

Comment: I don't believe in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Well, the reason why I am doing it this way is that initially I was building XElements, however, the server which I am communicating with does not believe in using XML prefixes, defining version or namespaces. The original programmer wrote it to expect data without these elements and I could not figure out a way to remove those parts of the XML without building the string as such. So it is either, rewrite the original server code, written in C, a language I do not know, to accomodate this. or build the string accordingly

Comment: As you can see xml linq in my code isn't generating prefix nor namespaces.  Your solution is a square wheel, mine is round wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape `"` with `\`:

```
String.Format("\"{0}\"<Parameter Id=\"{1}\">\"{2}\"</Parameter>", buffer, id, param);
```

You could also use a verbatim string literal, then you have to use double quotes:

```
String.Format(@"""{0}""<Parameter Id=""{1}"">""{2}""</Parameter>", buffer, id, param);
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I attempted to use your recommendation, escaping " with \ using your code and I received the same response as when I did the same thing.
  
`"\"<Conquest><User>ArchElf</User><Token>0123456789012345678901234567890</Token><Command>validate</Command>\"<Parameter Id=\"1\">\"Gemstone3\"</Parameter>"`

the \ appears literally in the string.

Using the second suggestion I got almost the same result, the slash is still appearing in my string.

Comment: @BackSlashAttack you must be viewing the string in the debugger, which *will* add extra backslashes for your comfort and convenience (or you're passing it to another bit of code which is adding backslashes before printing it). As suggested in another comment, either print it out or use the magnifying glass icon to view the string in its pure, raw form.